# Center and crop image with CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, ionic3

I need to Center and crop image with CSS. I have followed [**this article**](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/).But device UI output is somewhat different. Can you explain the behavior of this?

***This is the use case:***

> We don’t want to actually crop - just display the middle of the image.
>   Some of the docs people will upload will be docs so don’t want this to
>   be stretched.

**My question** is I don't know why it transforms (`1` image) `landscape` mode even though I got the image using `portrait` mode? Any explanation?

```css
photo {
    .photo {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        img {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        img.portrait {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
          }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <img [src]="data?.url class="portrait">
</div>
```

*UI:*

[image]

`1` - It shows when I used the device in `portrait` mode

`2` - when I used device in `landscape` mode

*Runtime code:*

[image]

Comment: can you use css background image for this ?

Comment: Here it takes using the device's camera and shows it to the user. @JacobGoh

Comment: Try `object-fit: cover` to the image tag

Comment: Where to put that? @Nimsrules

Comment: To the `img` tag

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great tip.Can you put it as an answer? @Nimsrules

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it by

```
img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

It works the same as `background-size: cover` but it's used for `img` tags instead of background images

[**Reference**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)