# How do I resize an image in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

How do I resize an image in CodeIgniter?

This is my code...

```
{
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        // Set your config up
        $config['image_library']    = "gd2";      
        $config['source_image']     = './uploads/header_images/' .$filename;
        $config['new_image']        = './uploads/header_images/thumbnail/'.$filename;       
        $config['create_thumb']     = TRUE;      
        $config['maintain_ratio']   = false;      
        $config['width'] = "50";      
        $config['height'] = "50";
        // $config['quality']  = '100';
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        // Do your manipulation
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        } 
        // $this->image_lib->clear();     
    }
```

my image is been streched i want image to maintain aspect ratio

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47052267/2427237

Comment: can you provide a before and after picture? also note: "Since the maintain_ratio option is enabled, the thumb will be as *close* to the target width and height as possible while preserving the original aspect ratio" from docs

Comment: @Nimsrules i tried this but it didn't solved my issue...any other possible way to do?

Comment: @Alex https://resizeimage.net/  hi alex can you please upload image on this link after uploading that i want to achieve number 4 option in that which of resize image

Comment: @Saad Shaikh you need to produce a working snippet for someone to debug it for you - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: no i mean can you show us an example of what your uploader is doing. a before and after picture. then another after picture with maintain_ratio

Answer (score 1):

Set this value to true:

```
$config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
```